# Why rendering time decreases for a View indepedently of the technique used as long as it's at the end? (Backbone.View, Raw JQuery or a Simple View)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm some kind intrigued about a weird behavior (at least to me at this time) while testing View Rendering. It appears that rendering time varies more according to the order of the statements and much less according to the technique of rendering.
I made a code pen that renders a simple input field wrapped inside:

- A Backbone View
- A simple custom view
- A Raw HTML string attached to the DOM using JQuery

[Rendering time Backbone.View vs Simple View vs Raw JQuery](http://codepen.io/mogarick/pen/qmoph)

It appears that rendering time decreases with order, being the last object the one that consumes less time for rendering.

BBView takes longer to render when it executes first but if you cut the code snippet and past it at the end, the render time is gonna be the lowest of the 3. Same thing happens for any of the 3 ways of rendering de input field.

I don't understand at this moment what's the reason for this. Does anyone knows why is this happening?

Is there a better way to make this test? thank you in advance.

Comment: Timing something that takes such a short amount of time is not going to give reliable results.

Comment: Do you think rendering about 100 times same view could improve such reliability?

Comment: Yes, doing it repeatedly would make the timing more meaningful.  In this case I bet there are some JavaScript environment startup issues involved.

Comment: What I can see is that the difference between the fist and the second is huge. The only thing I can beliebe is that the fist time you use a type of element the element "Class" is loaded into memory, and these is an expensive work, putting that aside. The use of JQuery is a little more computationally expensive because is a general use utility. Is not a bad utility but the use of the library add several lines of code that you might never use.